# Convert a simple command line to an NT service

Tags: windows, service, wrapper

I have a single program, which is used here essentially as a service.

Currently, I need to start this from a command line, as

```
program_name.exe arg1 arg2 arg3
```

And stopping it happens by killing it from the task manager.

I liked it better, if somehow - maybe through a wrapper - I could install this as a service, to be able to manage it by the `services.msc`. Is it possible? If yes, how?

Comment: You don't have the source of that exe? How about https://github.com/kohsuke/winsw/

Comment: @rene I have, but 1) it is in python 2) I did only source changes if there isn't any alternative.

Comment: [nssm](http://nssm.cc/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe, you can use srvany.exe from Microsoft Windows 2003 Resource Kit and SC commands.
Here is an example using google drive.
http://www.myrtec.com.au/kb/331